# How to structure a multiple post endpoints with node / express.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express

How can I successfully configure my routes to access multiple methods on my controller accordingly to the endpoint and parameters passed to the URL?

When accessing /companies/:companyId/createCheques I would like to call the method createCheques in cheques controller but it is still calling createCheque.

I tried adding the line below to routes/cheques.js but it did not work.

```js
router.route('/:companyId/createCheques').post(createCheques)
```

```js
// routes/companies.js
const express = require('express')

const {
    getCompanies,
    getCompany,
    deleteCompany,
    createCompany,
    updateCompany,
} = require('../controllers/companies')

// Include other resource routers 
const userRouter = require('./users')
const chequeRouter = require('./cheques')
const redeemRouter = require('./redeems')

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })

// Re-route into another resources routers
router.use('/:companyId/users', userRouter)
router.use('/:companyId/cheques', chequeRouter)
router.use('/:companyId/createCheques', chequeRouter)
router.use('/:companyId/redeems', redeemRouter)


router
    .route('/')
    .get(getCompanies)
    .post(createCompany)

router
    .route('/:id')
    .get(getCompany)
    .put(updateCompany)
    .delete(deleteCompany)


module.exports = router;
```

```js
// routes/cheques.js
const express = require('express')

const {
    getCheques,
    getCheque,
    deleteCheque,
    createCheque,
    createCheques,
    updateCheque
} = require('../controllers/cheques')

// when more than 1 url param is possible to the same route, mergeParams must to be set to true
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })

// Advanced results 
const Cheque = require('../models/Cheque')
const advancedResults = require('../middleware/advancedResults')


router
    .route('/')
    .get(advancedResults(Cheque, 'cheques'), getCheques)
    .post(createCheque)
    .post(createCheques)


router
    .route('/:id')
    .get(getCheque)
    .put(updateCheque)
    .delete(deleteCheque)


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are defining two POST controllers for the exact same route.

If you want to call both controllers `createCheque` and `createCheques`, when a POST is done to `:companyId/createCheques/`, you only need to add `next()` on the last line of `createCheque`, just like a middleware. See https://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#router

If you only want to call one controller, then you need to create a separate route for the other controller on your **routes/cheques.js** file.

```
router
 .route('/cheques') //here the complete path would be companyId/createCheques/cheques
 .post(createCheques)
```